# Automorphism group of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-groups, permutation-groups, algebraic-graph-theory

Suppose $\Gamma$ is a simple graph and $G=\mathrm{Aut}(\Gamma)$ is the automorphism group of $\Gamma$. If $G$ stabilizes a subgraph $\Gamma_1$,, and $G_0$ is the point-wise stabiliser of the set $V(\Gamma_1)$ w.r.t. the action of $G$ on $V(\Gamma)$, that is, $G_0=\cap_{x\in V(\Gamma_1)}\ \mathrm{Stab}_G(x) $ and $G_1=\mathrm{Aut}(\Gamma_1)$, is it true that $G$ is the semidirect product of $G_0$ and $G_1$?

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry for missing the "$G$ stabilizes $\Gamma_1$" condition in the previous edit)

The answer is no. Consider $\Gamma = ([4], \{12, 13, 23, 14\})$. $G$ stabilizes $\Gamma_1$ = the edge $14$. $G_0 = G$, and $|G_1| = 2$, while for the semiderict product we must have $|N \rtimes H| = |N| \times |H|$.

Comment: in your example it seems G does mot stabilize $\Gamma_1$!

Comment: In new example  I think G stabilize an edge but I wrote  vertex!

Comment: I think "$G$ stabilizes a subgraph $\Gamma$" is typically understood as "sets of vertices and edges of $\Gamma$ are invariant w.r.t $G$" (this is the difference between stabilizer and point-wise stabilizer of the set). In any case, both endpoints of the edge are stabilized too.

Comment: I do not mean point wise stabilizer, who edit my question?

Comment: I wrote stabilizer in question

Comment: Your (initially present, edited by nobody) definition of $G_0$ describes precisely point-wise stabilizer, and "$G$ stabilizes a subgraph $\Gamma$" condition may need to be clarified in two possible ways, but the answer applies in any case.

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: Is it possible to find some additional conditions such that yields my assertion?

Comment: Be as it may, this probably deserves a separate question (if possible to articulate precisely).

Comment: @maryam: re "who edit my question": the answer to this is (as you can just look up for yourself by clicking on the 'edited...' link): two people edited your rather unclear initial question, and it was me who introduced 'point-stabilizer' and I stand by that edit: from the outset, your OP contained a *formula* which unambiguously defines a **point**wise stabilizer subgroup of $G$. I took the mathematical formulae to have priority in trying to clarify your question. I am sorry that this is not what you *meant*, yet it *was* what you **wrote**. Feel free to make any clarifications you need.

Comment: And to make all this a bit redundant and checkable: the formula in question, which (up to the newly introduced upright font) was present from the first version of the OP, is $\cap_{x\in V(\Gamma_1)}\mathrm{Stab}_G(x)$. This unambiguously defines a *point*wise stabilizer subgroup.